# Removing duplicate rows that match the name column but are with ten minutes of each other in the time column

Tags: excel, forms, duplicates

I have a google forms check-in spreadsheet where students are joining our zoom for assistance and they will fill out a quick google form to let us know that they are joining. For some reason, students record multiple entries on the form before they join. I was wondering if there was a simple way to delete duplicate name entries en mass that are recorded within 10 minutes or less of each other?Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: In Excel I'd suggest using Power Query, to set up sequential 10 minute groups (at one minute intervals) and looking for the duplicates within each group. Also, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)